# What is the best way to get data from Firebird to SQL Server and vice versa?

Tags: sql, sql-server, firebird

I want to get data from one SQL Server to Firebird, and then from that same Firebird database to another SQL Server.

This is the first time I am doing this so I am pretty lost.

Any tips are appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/import-export-data/import-and-export-data-with-the-sql-server-import-and-export-wizard?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: StackOverflow rules: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: It seems this kind of questions is for a different community - for example https://dba.stackexchange.com/tour